# With PHP, how can I replace <a href="xxx"> tags with <span data-href="xxx"> tags?

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to completely eliminate certain `<a>` tags, but retain the text and original href in a classed `<span>` tag.

**Before:** `<a href="www.example.com">Click here</a>`

**After:** `<span class="myClass" data-href="www.example.com">Click Here</span>`

I've managed to replace the link with plain text with the code below, but learned I cannot include any markup.  How can I modify the code to accomplish the before/after from above??

```
$domd = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$domd->loadHTML($output);
$domx = new DOMXPath($domd);
foreach ($domx->query("//a") as $link) {
    $href = $link->getAttribute("href");
    if (strpos($href, 'oursite.com') === false) {
        continue;  // Don't change links to our site.
    }
    $text = $domd->createTextNode($link->nodeValue);
    $link->parentNode->replaceChild($text, $link);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here what you can do:

```
$domd = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$domd->loadHTML($output);
$domx = new DOMXPath($domd);
foreach ($domx->query("//a") as $link) {
    $href = $link->getAttribute("href");
    // by the way, it should be NOT false to skip your urls
    if (strpos($href, 'oursite.com') !== false) {
        continue;  // Don't change links to our site.
    }
    // create span-element
    $span = $domd->createElement('span', $link->nodeValue);
    // set span attributes
    $span->setAttribute('class', "myClass");
    $span->setAttribute('data-href', $href);

    // replace $link with $span
    $link->parentNode->replaceChild($span, $link);
}
```

Comment: Ah, typo on the === false, but more importantly THANK you....been all morning trying to make this happen....where do I send cash?!!!